# How to specify request parameters with "ids" in spyne?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, spyne

I have been tasked to created a SOAP service for one of our partners. The partner provided me a WSDL as specification, that I should implement on our side. I made already quite some progress, yet now I hit a wall.

How can I implement this (the `<ns:Criteria id="?">` line is the problem)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:SearchRequest>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <ns:Criteria id="?">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:LocationIds>?</ns:LocationIds>
            <ns:Type>?</ns:Type>
         </ns:Criteria>
         <ns:Channel>?</ns:Channel>
         <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
      </ns:SearchRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Python code that provides the Service currently looks like this:

```
class CriteriaModel(ComplexModel):
    id = String
    LocationIds = String
    Type = String

class SomeService(Service):

    @rpc(
        Array(CriteriaModel, wrapped=False),
        _returns=Container,
        _in_message_name='SearchRequest',
        _out_message_name='SearchResponse'
    )
    def Search(ctx, criterias):
        # pass
        # TODO: implement the logic
```

Yet with this approach I get this result:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ava="http://..." xmlns:book="...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ava:SearchRequest>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ava:Criteria>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <book:id>?</book:id>
            <book:LocationIds>?</book:LocationIds>
            <book:Type>?</book:Type>
         </ava:Criteria>
      </ava:SearchRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this a custom model that I have to implement here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. That "id" thing is called an Attribute.

I replaced

```
class CriteriaModel(ComplexModel):
    id = String
    LocationIds = String
    Type = String
```

with:

```
class CriteriaModel(ComplexModel):
    id = XmlAttribute(String)
    LocationIds = String
    Type = String
```

And its rendered as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ava="http://..." xmlns:book="...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ava:SearchRequest>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ava:Criteria id="?">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <book:LocationIds>?</book:LocationIds>
            <book:Type>?</book:Type>
         </ava:Criteria>
      </ava:SearchRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```